# How can I contact the asker of a deleted question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71702/what-version-of-norwegian-is-spoken-on-their-state-media) was asked and deleted.

I want to let the asker know that their question already has an [answer here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66989/41775).

How can I contact them now that the answer is deleted? I don't even remember their user name, all I have is the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I can think of, as the post is deleted recently, google cache [can help you with this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71702/what-version-of-norwegian-is-spoken-on-their-state-media). Appears that the OP was [this user](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/45583/to-ga).

Then you could create a chatroom for you and them and tell OP what you were going to do.

Comment: If Google cache missed it, another option is asking in chat, and 10k user of the site can take a look and see who posted it.